# checking condition after response

Tags: iphone

I am sending a request and on receiving the response i need to check the condition and only then navigate to the next screen but then this condition is checked even before i receive the response. How can i check the condition only after receiving the response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using NSURL Connection or any Component??

Try using NSURL Connection delegates. Check out this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection .

I think any of the two methods will work.
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data OR
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

Comment: I am using NSURL Connection it's an asynchronous request

Comment: Try using NSURL Connection delegates. Check out this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection.  I think any of the two methods will work.                                                   -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  OR                                                               - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [ASI](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library.  It is nicer to use than NSURLConnection.

Either way, you should start the request asynchronously and set the delegate to self.

When you receive the response in the delegate callback you can then continue to the next screen.

For ASI you would do ...

```
- (void)dorequest
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];

   // Do no do anything else in this method. 
   // wait for the response to call your delegate method
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   [self loadNextScreen];
}
```

`NSURLConnection` would use similar code.  Just make sure you use the asynchronous method.

Answer (score 0):

i feel the problem wasn't explained properly because it was misunderstood. I am using NSURLConnection and the request is an asynchronous one, so that was not the question. I needed some code to be executed only after the data download was completed.

I got an answer; by using NSNotifications. In my parser class within connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection method i post Notifications. In my viewcontroller class i added an observer where i execute the needed code.

For more help see : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Thanks